# Documentation for LLVM ARM Assembler Directives

Tags: assembly, arm, clang, llvm, cortex-m

At the moment I'm looking at assembler code for the ARM Cortex-M3 generated by LLVM. LLVM generates a lot of assembler directives. As you can see in the example below:

```
    .text
    .syntax unified
    .eabi_attribute 67, "2.09"  @ Tag_conformance
    .cpu    cortex-m3
    .eabi_attribute 6, 10   @ Tag_CPU_arch
    .eabi_attribute 7, 77   @ Tag_CPU_arch_profile
    .eabi_attribute 8, 0    @ Tag_ARM_ISA_use
    .eabi_attribute 9, 2    @ Tag_THUMB_ISA_use
    .eabi_attribute 17, 1   @ Tag_ABI_PCS_GOT_use
    .eabi_attribute 20, 1   @ Tag_ABI_FP_denormal
    .eabi_attribute 21, 1   @ Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions
    .eabi_attribute 23, 3   @ Tag_ABI_FP_number_model
    .eabi_attribute 34, 0   @ Tag_CPU_unaligned_access
    .eabi_attribute 24, 1   @ Tag_ABI_align_needed
    .eabi_attribute 25, 1   @ Tag_ABI_align_preserved
    .eabi_attribute 38, 1   @ Tag_ABI_FP_16bit_format
    .eabi_attribute 14, 0   @ Tag_ABI_PCS_R9_use
    .file   "simple.bc"
    .globl  main
    .align  2
    .type   main,%function
    .code   16                      @ @main
    .thumb_func
main:
    .fnstart
.Leh_func_begin0:
@ BB#0:
    .pad    #16
    sub sp, #16
    movs    r0, #0
    str r0, [sp, #12]
    movs    r1, #42
    str r1, [sp, #8]
    movs    r1, #23
    str r1, [sp, #4]
    ldr r1, [sp, #8]
    subs    r1, #23
    str r1, [sp]
    add sp, #16
    bx  lr
.Ltmp0:
    .size   main, .Ltmp0-main
.Leh_func_end0:
    .fnend


    .ident  "clang version 3.6.2 (tags/RELEASE_362/final)"
    .section    ".note.GNU-stack","",%progbits
```

I found the ARM specific assembler directives here: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Directives.html

However I couldn't find the missing ones and an explanation if those directives have to appear in a certain order. Is there a complete documentation for all those assembler directives and there order?

Comment: AFAICS all the directives used there are covered by the GAS documentation - which ones are "the missing ones"?

Comment: Could you provide a link for GAS documentation?

Comment: Er, you linked to it in the question - sorry if it wasn't clear GAS = **G**NU **As**sembler = Binutils "as". The non-machine-specific directives (e.g. `.text`, `.align`, etc.) are covered in section 7.

Comment: Ah, thank you! What about `.Leh_func_begin0`, `.Ltmp0`, `.Leh_func_end0` and `@ BB#0`?

Comment: .Lsomething is a label not a directive

Comment: I would assume the BB something is also generated similarly and not a directive.  maybe a note to the compiler author for debugging.

Comment: **BB** is compiler writer speak for 'basic block' so it is a code chunk comment.  It is an assembler comment, not a directive.

Comment: To read assembly code you really need to have a fair understanding of the fundamental syntax stuff: ["A label is a symbol immediately followed by a colon (`:`)"](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Statements.html#Statements); ["The presence of a `@` anywhere on a line indicates the start of a comment that extends to the end of that line."](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM_002dChars.html#ARM_002dChars).